# My cat buddi gets some kind of black stuff in its eyes, is that a problem?

Tags: cats, health

My cats been getting some kind of black stuff around its eyes, is it normal?

Answer (score 2):

Is this black (or dark brown) gunky stuff around his eyes? It -=may=- be that your cat just has a cold. It may be that your cat has feline herpes (viral rhinotracheitis, or FVR), or a fungal infection. Take the cat to a vet and ask them about it. (Hard to guess at what it might be without either a photo or a clearer description; but...going just on your description, there could be many causes. A vet will track down the problem and be able to suggest diagnoses, if they are necessary.)

Comment: OK i will upload the picture shortly, and yes today i am taking my kitty to the vet.

Answer (score 0):

A small amount of 'crust' around the eye is fairly common in cats and you can use a tissue to help them get rid of it.  Cats like Persians have a slightly worse issue than normal.  It is similar to the 'sand' that the Sandman is supposed to sprinkle in kids eyes.

If it is a large amount, or the eye looks red, then a vet visit is in order.

Comment: Does not look red, just a chunk of black stuff, dark circles like

Answer (score 0):

Hate to be wishy-washy.

It could be perfectly normal, or it could be a problem requiring vet care.  Most likely it is the first.

As cats age, some start to accumulate some black gunk below the lowest part of the eye (I think the tear duct is there).  Some people assign the highly technical term "eye booger" to this stuff.  It's not a big problem, but removing it is probably a good idea for hygiene's sake.

As my cats have gone past age 15, some of them have had this issue.  I notice it is worse in winter when it is dry.  I simply clean the area (very gently) with my finger.  Note your cat will probably not be terribly keen about you doing this.

Right now my "baby" (a 16 yr old Manx) is not doing this, I think, because the air is warmer and more humid.  Another cat I have who is 18 never seems to have the problem (maybe she cleans her own eyes, maybe she has less buildup).  Another cat who is, I think, 16 has the problem less, and it is pretty much just during winter.

Comment: Yes i do clean its eyes everyday, however i have seen many Persian cats with clean eyes.

Comment: @DigitalGeeK I don't understand "however i have seen many Persian cats with clean eyes" what do you mean?  You've seen other cats of the same breed with clean eyes so you expect yours to be the same?  As I mentioned my cats didn't start getting this until they got older, and not all of them have it or in the same amount.  With my cats it is the feline equivalent of that gunk humans get on their tearducts (as oldcat indicates) except ours is beige and theirs is black.

Comment: From googling "cat eye booger" which had good returns (eye crusts) and bad returns (serious medical conditions).  I include some URLs since images may be copywrighted: http://www.whiskersandpurrs.com/2008/02/wowwwy-wowwwy-w.html (check out the orange and white tabby with a HUGE eye booger) http://www.petsadviser.com/pet-health/my-cat-always-eye-boogers/ (a more typical sized example).  With mine the eyelid(?) edge and tearduct are black and the "booger" is on the tearduct, not further down.